# The result of a database query is not getting displayed on my page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get details of products to be displayed on my webpage in a specific format by submitting an id number through a form. But no data is being displayed on submitting the query. I want the latest retrieved data to be appended below the already existing data on the same page from where the form was submitted.

This is my home.php :

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) )
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    // select loggedin users detail
    $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> ShopNGo </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#scan").on('click',function()
                {
                    var id =$("#id").val();
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "getdata.php",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('.results').append(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Hi' <?php echo $userRow['userEmail']; ?>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Sign Out</a>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <form name="products" method="POST" action="">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="scan" id="scan" value="SCAN">
                    <br><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
                </form>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <table border="0">
                <div class="results" id="results">
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

This is my getdata.php :

```
$query = "SELECT name, price, img FROM product WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $element = "<tr> <table border='0'> <tr>";
        $element .= "<img src='$row[img]'>";
        $element .= "<br>";
        $element .= $row["name"];
        $element .= "<br>";
        $element .= $row["price"];
        $element .= "</tr> </table> </tr>";
    }
}
echo $element;
```

This is dbconnect.php

```
<?php
    // this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
    error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
    // but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "#usernasme";
    $password = "#password";
    $dbname = "#dbname";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ( !$conn )
    {
        die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_error());
    }
?>
```

FYI - I am using a php script that maintains a user login session that connects to a database and keeps a user logged in until he signs out. Is there by any an interference between the two scripts: one that maintains user sessions and another that accesses database for getting product details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is Jquery script link?

Comment: First of all,assuming u are including the jquery library, you have a syntax error here : $('results').append(data); it should be $('.results').append(data);

Comment: I have no idea about the jquery library. How to include it and where? please help @lazy_coder

Comment: Do you get any error, or what seems to be the problem? Do you carry over the post variable successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any data via ajax; 
I'm supposing that you'have included jquery correctly; 
 Then try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#scan").on('click',function(){
      var id =$("#id").val();
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "getdata.php",
               data: {id: id},
               success: function(data){
               $('.results').append(data);
              }
      });

    });

  });
```

Good luck

Comment: I have no idea about the jquery library. How to include it and where? please help @lazy_coder

Comment: put this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  right before </body>

Comment: i edited the code as you said... but the problem persists... please help soon. also please read the fyi at the end once.. thanks